# How to count the number of matches?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$str = 'this is a string';
```

And this is my pattern: [`/i/g`](https://regex101.com/r/rP5pD8/2). There is three occurrence *(as you see in the string above, it is containing three `i`)*. Now I need to count that. How can I get that number?

Comment: There is no g modifier in php, use preg_match_all that returns the number of matches.

Comment: think you may use `substr_count`

Comment: Or use `preg_replace` with *count* argument.

Comment: Ah ok thank you .. I will give it a try

Comment: A hint: never simplify complex requirements like this. I did not answer because there the question feels unclear. It is either too simple (given your input data) or unclear (since the input is too simple).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right .. From then on I will ask by my exact information. To be honest, this time I tried to ask the concept of my question, not my exact question *(information)*. I wanted you guys get it simply.

Comment: Good. And Hint #2: Please search before posting an answer. You have asked so many basic questions that have good SO answers already. Just go to google, type "php regex" + what you need. "count specific words", "count characters", "count matches", "split with comma outside quotes"..... Etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Owkey thank you for the hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) as well as [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
echo substr_count("this is a string", "i"); // will echo 3
echo $k_count = preg_match_all('/i/i', 'this is a string', $out);  // will echo 3
```

other method is convert into array and then count it:

```
$arr = str_split('this is a string');
$counts = array_count_values($arr);

print_r($counts);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [t] => 2
    [h] => 1
    [i] => 3
    [s] => 3
    [ ] => 3
    [a] => 1
    [r] => 1
    [n] => 1
    [g] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

```
$str = 'this is a string';
echo substr_count($str, "i"); // 3
```

You can also use [mb_substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr-count.php)

```
$str = 'this is a string';
echo mb_substr_count($str, "i"); // 3
```

**substr_count** — Count the number of substring occurrences

**mb_substr_count** — Count the number of substring occurrences

Comment: In reality the pattern is different, It isn't just a letter.

Comment: @stack we can't read your mind, you need to provide the exact data or related data.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You are right .. but actually my exact pattern is much complex and I tried to ask my question clearly.

Comment: @stack: Provide your exact pattern so we can help you accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) could be a better fit.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$subject = "a test string a";
$pattern = '/a/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Prints:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => a ) )
```